# How to make title of screen dynamic?

Tags: reactjs, redux, native

I have 2 screens listProducts and detailProduct.
when I navigate from the list to detail I get all info about the product.
so I would like to display product name on header of screen.
 I have made this method

DetailProduct.js:

```
componentWillReceiveProps(nextProps){
   if(nextProps.product.name !== undefined)
       this.props.navigation.setParams({ Name:  nextProps.product.name })
}
```

Navigator.js:

```
detailProduct: {
  screen: detailProduct,
  navigationOptions: ({ navigation }) => 
   ({title:navigation.getParam('Name', 'DefaultName'),})
}
```

but I get this error:
[Invariant Violation: Maximum update depth exceeded. This can happen when a component repeatedly calls setState inside componentWillUpdate or componentDidUpdate. React limits the number of nested updates to prevent infinite loops.]
knowing that I use redux.
Pleace How can I fix this probleme, how can I make header's title dynamic.
thanks

Answer (score 0):

It seems that you need to change the condition from `if(nextProps.product.name !== undefined)` to `if(nextProps.product.name !== undefined && nextProps.product.name !== this.props.navigation.getParam('Name'))`.

Otherwise, you will change the state every time.

[Working demo](https://snack.expo.io/@teimurjan/react-navigation)

Comment: Thank you very much teimurjan. I can't beleive it works, Thanks again

Comment: @zakitutu no probs :)